# prevent the link to open if it contain this condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Sorry for this question I think it's not difficult but I'm new to PHP, I tried to show some images of products with the link, If the item is available **$row['p_status']=='1'** ok the link will be opened else it **display an alert**, but I tried to write some code inside while loop but when I test it, it display **many alert** according the number of those items which is $row['p_status']=='0' **if I have 5 products** which it it's not available if I click on an product it show me five alert.

Please help me this is my code.

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);                   
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
    <div class="column">
            <img src="<?=get_image($row['image']);?>">
             <span>Add to Your Cart </span>
            <a href="mycart.php?add=<?=$row['product_id'];?>" id="a">
            <?php
            if ($row['pro_status']=='0') {
                # the link above not open but, how to do with code?
            }
            ?>
    </div>
<?php 
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to post what it was that you tried. What you wrote suggests it.

Comment: Btw, ID's are meant to be unique. This is in regards to the href. Probably why or a big reason why the code you tried failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an if statement to check if the status is 1.
In case it's 1 you show the link with href otherwise you call the onclick event to display the out of stock alert.

This is one of the solutions (easier for beginners):

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);                   
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
    <div class="column">
            <img src="<?=get_image($row['image']);?>">
            <?php if($row['pro_status'] == 1) { ?>
            <a href="mycart.php?add=<?=$row['product_id'];?>">
              Add to Your Cart 
            </a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <button onclick="return alert('Out of stock!')">Add to cart</a>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php 
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Cool! Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to have click event return false.

Following should do it:

```
if ($row['pro_status']=='0') {
    $("#a").click(function(){
        return false;
    });
}
```

Another solution is to use preventDefault()

```
if ($row['pro_status']=='0') {
    $("#a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at their href again. Most specifically what the "id" is.